# Microsoft Project Online CSOM Authentication working but unable to load projects

Tags: azure, .net-core, sharepoint-online, csom

I switched my application to .net core and started using the new .net core CSOM for sharepoint.
I followed the [Using modern authentication with CSOM for .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard) documentation, but I still can't query the list of projects using the "ProjectContext".
The authentication seems be to working, I get a token but when I try to "Load" `context.Projects` it doesn't load anything :

```
using var context = new CSOMDemo.AuthenticationManager().GetContext(new Uri($"https://{company}.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa"), email, password);
context.Load(context.Projects);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var project = context.Projects.First(); // crash, Sequence contains no elements
```

If I do the same thing but using the .Net Framework with `SharePointOnlineCredentials`, the same url, username and password works.

The permissions in the application in azure seems to be configured correctly since if I remove the `SharePoint> AllSites.FullControl` and then try to run the same code, I get a `ServerUnauthorizedAccessException` at the `ExecuteQuery` line.

I changed the `ClientContext` for a `ProjectContext` in the `Authentication.GetContext` method.

Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

Thanks,

### Environment details (*development & target environment*)

- **Your Developer Environment**:  Windows 10
- **Target Environment**: SharePoint Online
- **Framework**:  .NET Core v3.1
- **Tooling**: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I also posted this github, with no answer for a while :
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5956

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Ishan no! I never got an answer on the SharePoint github and we started working on other stuff and just never came back to this!